# How to use a Hershey vector font in latex?

Tags: fonts

I would love to use the font like Roman Simplex, from the [Hershey fonts collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey_fonts), in a latex document. Is there any package that allows me to do it?

N.B.: it has nothing to do with the font so-called "Hershey Old English".

Edit:
a sample of the font I'm looking for. Even if they are few letters, it gives an idea.
[image]

Comment: On the site https://emergent.unpythonic.net/software/hershey there is a file called `tex-hershey.zip` which contains a (plain) TeX example. I couldn't get it to work easily, but you could take a look and maybe modify your current question to ask about specific issues with that code (or other code you might find somewhere).

Comment: @Marijn, thanks a lot. I got it compiled after some effort, but this is not the font I look for. The numbers are very similar, but the font is a script font, and I am looking for a "classic" sans serif. I added an image to the original question.

Comment: The Debian package [gsfonts-other](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gsfonts-other) contains the Hershey fonts in Type 1 format.  You could convert these to OpenType with FontForge and then use them with xetex or luatex.  Otherwise you’d need to write support files for the `.pfb` fonts, and that’s probably more trouble than it’s worth.

Comment: A new package allows to use hershey with metapost. https://ctan.org/pkg/hershey-mp

Answer (score 1):

You may download the **RomanS** TrueType font (e.g. from [this site](https://www.wfonts.com/font/romans)) and use a method to get this font working with (`Xe` or `Lua`)(`La`)`TeX` on your platform, for which you may have a look at [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525779/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-latex).

Similar procedure for RomanT (e.g. from [that site](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/RomanT/)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a collection of TTF fonts projected from the Hershey fonts https://github.com/yangcht/Hershey_font_TTF. You can install the fonts and use them via XeLaTeX options.