# Is there a way to generate single stroke path from latex math like Hershey fonts?

Tags: fonts, svg

I am trying to create an automated text animation tool. For regular text, I can use a single-stroked font like Hershey font in Inkscape and then I can export it to svg from which I can get the path information,  which gets the job done. But I don't know how to achieve the same for latex math. Is there a way to generate latex math with single strokes?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442508/how-to-use-a-hershey-vector-font-in-latex  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544654/math-font-as-single-stroke-no-fill  As far as I can tell, the latter post is aimed at a very similar use case as you are imagining, //   Also, instead of creating your own automated text animation tool, have you considered using something with a lot of existing community support like https://www.manim.community/ ?